# indexing over list of locations in 2d array efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

This function takes some tictactoe boards and return what moves were legal attempts (-1 represents an "O", 1 represents an "X", and 0 is an empty space)

```
def legal_locations(boards, moves):

    legal_idxs, legal_locs = [], []
    illegal_idxs, illegal_locs = [], []

    for i, j in enumerate(moves):

        # The middle index here is 0 because the locations > 0 are reserved for historical states.
        # We only want to examine the current board state.
        if boards[i][0][j]:  # This location is occupied
            illegal_idxs.append(i)
            illegal_locs.append(j)

        else:  # unoccupied
            legal_idxs.append(i)
            legal_locs.append(j)

    return (legal_idxs, legal_locs), (illegal_idxs, illegal_locs)
```

It works fine, but "boards" is just a rectangular numpy array, and "moves" is a list. I'm thinking there has to be a faster way to accomplish this using numpy. Any ideas?

If it can't be made more efficient - it would be nice to know what about this problem makes it hard to optimize.

edit:

```
boards =
array([[[ 0,  1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0],
        [ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0,  0,  1, -1,  0,  0,  0, -1],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  1, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]]])
```

This boards array shows two games, which each have 4 historical states.

```
moves =
       [2, 8]
```

This moves array shows two indices.
The locations of interest are thus:

```
boards[0][0][2]
boards[1][0][8]
```

So in this example, we would have the following return from our fxn:

```
([0], [2]), ([1], [8])
```

EDIT2: A more core example:

@AlexanderCécile part of the problem I suppose is that I don't know how to use a list as an index. For instance, I don't know how to reduce this loop...

```
for i in range(legal.shape[0]):
  legal[i, 0, index_list[i]] = -1
```

Where len(index_list) == len(legal)

If I could do that, then everything else should snap into place using np.nonzero

Comment: Could you share more of your code, and some test data? See: [mcve].

Comment: I’m also curious as to why the second dimension is used for “time”, I would have expected the first dimension for that instead. Finally, how is `moves` organized? You’re using `enumerate()`, so I’m not sure how it could be structured.

Comment: I agree with @AlexanderCécile -- it would help to see the data. As a rule, you really never need to loop with NumPy, there's almost always a way to do what you want with indexing or similar -- and it's almost always much faster.

Comment: You can use `numpy.nonzero()`, for self-explanatory purposes.

Comment: Only just saw your edit, will give it a try tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

Cast the array to `bool`, and then use `np.where` to generate indices corresponding to `True` values (`~` operator will invert the cast array). For a single board:

```
array = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [-1, 1, 0], [1, -1, -1]])
mask = array.astype(bool)
illegal_row, illegal_col = np.where(mask)
legal_row, legal_col = np.where(~mask)
```

This can be extended to multiple boards by running over a leading index.

Comment: From the [`numpy.where()` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html): _When only condition is provided, this function is a shorthand for np.asarray(condition).nonzero(). Using nonzero directly should be preferred, as it behaves correctly for subclasses._ The cast to `bool` is also unnecessary.